# Get MongoDB Query Results by Unit Time

Tags: stored-procedures, spring-data, mongodb-query, date-range

I have the following method:

```
public StatisticsValues computeStatistics(String Id, Date startDate, Date endDate, UnitTime unitTime){  
    //Code here
    return StatisticsValues;  
}
```

where UnitTime is an enum:

```
public enum UnitTime {  
    MINUTE,
    HOUR,
    DAY,
    MONTH,
    YEAR  
}
```

An example from my collection in MongoDB could be:

```
{  
  "id": "idValue",
  "value": true,
  "date": "2016-01-21T03:00:00.000Z"
}
```

For example if the range of dates would be: [2016-03-02,2016-04-02] and the UnitTime would be: HOUR, I'd  have to divide the range of dates in 24 ranges. 
If in a range of an hour I'd have the followings values: {true, true, false, false}, I could return a numeric value: 0,5.
However, I don't want to divide the ranges in Java, because It'd have a bad performance: if the range of dates covers 10 days, I'd have to make 240 queries!

I'm searching a way throught mongoDB to resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: could you clarify expected result - or give us a document example?